# What's the use of textStyle property in ElevatedButton?

Tags: flutter

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black), // Not working
  ),
  child: Text('Hello'),
)
```

There's `textStyle` property in the `styleFrom` method but when I provide a color to it, it doesn't change the color of the `Text` supplied. So, what's the use of that property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*First of all, sorry if i am a bit inaccurate on some technical aspects on ***Dart*** and **Flutter**: i am new to these technologies :)*

### Short answer

The use of `textStyle` property in the `styleFrom` method is to set the style of the text on the button. Nevertheless, even if the use of `color` property in `textStyle` is to set the color of text, it is primarily for the use of `Text` Widget. In `Button`s, [`foregroundColor` has preference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/foregroundColor.html). Other than that, style set in `textStyle` is applied to the button's text (`fontWeight`, etc.)

Set `foregroundColor` to `null` and `color` property from `textStyle` will be taken instead (keep reading for details!).

### Long answer

So, after i double read your question i got intrigued and went to the documentation. [There](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/foregroundColor.html) i found that

> [foregroundColor property] is typically used instead of the color of the textStyle.
> All of the components that compute defaults from ButtonStyle values
> compute a default foregroundColor and use that instead of the
> textStyle's color.

Ok, but when i tried to retrieve the foregroundColor property from a button that has called styleFrom method, i got null

```dart
...
ElevatedButton(
  // prints null
  onPressed: () {
    print("foreground is ${ElevatedButton.styleFrom(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)).foregroundColor}");
  },
...
```

and still, the color property of textStyle is ignored, so there had to be something else...

It was then that i realized that in the [docu](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/styleFrom.html) for `styleFrom` they write

> The onPrimary, and onSurface colors are used to to create a
> MaterialStateProperty ButtonStyle.foregroundColor value

And further, looking at the implementation of ElevatedButton i found that there is a method called defaultStyleOf, [which](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/defaultStyleOf.html)

> Defines the button's default appearance.

And even further, its implementation had this line

```dart
...
return styleFrom(
  primary: colorScheme.primary,
  onPrimary: colorScheme.onPrimary,
...
```

where

```
final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
final ColorScheme colorScheme = theme.colorScheme;
```

So i realized that behind the scenes, `foregroundColor` might be assigned to the value of `onPrimary` set by the `defaultStyleOf` method which is taken from `Theme.of(context)`.

With this knowledge i decided to make an experiment and create a custom button which would extend `ElevatedButton` and which overrides `defaultStyleOf` with `onPrimary` set to `null`. By doing this, the button's `foregroundColor` is set to `null`, and then the `color` from `textStyle` should come into play, so i wrote

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MyElevatedButton(child: Text("Hello"), textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),);
  }
}

@immutable
class _ElevatedButtonDefaultBackground extends MaterialStateProperty<Color?> with Diagnosticable {
  _ElevatedButtonDefaultBackground(this.primary, this.onSurface);

  final Color? primary;
  final Color? onSurface;

  @override
  Color? resolve(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled))
      return onSurface?.withOpacity(0.12);
    return primary;
  }
}

@immutable
class _ElevatedButtonDefaultForeground extends MaterialStateProperty<Color?> with Diagnosticable {
  _ElevatedButtonDefaultForeground(this.onPrimary, this.onSurface);

  final Color? onPrimary;
  final Color? onSurface;

  @override
  Color? resolve(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled))
      return onSurface?.withOpacity(0.38);
    return onPrimary;
  }
}

@immutable
class _ElevatedButtonDefaultOverlay extends MaterialStateProperty<Color?> with Diagnosticable {
  _ElevatedButtonDefaultOverlay(this.onPrimary);

  final Color onPrimary;

  @override
  Color? resolve(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered))
      return onPrimary.withOpacity(0.08);
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused) || states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
      return onPrimary.withOpacity(0.24);
    return null;
  }
}

@immutable
class _ElevatedButtonDefaultElevation extends MaterialStateProperty<double> with Diagnosticable {
  _ElevatedButtonDefaultElevation(this.elevation);

  final double elevation;

  @override
  double resolve(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled))
      return 0;
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered))
      return elevation + 2;
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused))
      return elevation + 2;
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
      return elevation + 6;
    return elevation;
  }
}

@immutable
class _ElevatedButtonDefaultMouseCursor extends MaterialStateProperty<MouseCursor?> with Diagnosticable {
  _ElevatedButtonDefaultMouseCursor(this.enabledCursor, this.disabledCursor);

  final MouseCursor? enabledCursor;
  final MouseCursor? disabledCursor;

  @override
  MouseCursor? resolve(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled))
      return disabledCursor;
    return enabledCursor;
  }
}

class MyElevatedButton extends ElevatedButton {

  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final Widget child;


  MyElevatedButton({required this.textStyle, required this.child}) : super(child: Text("topo",), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(textStyle: textStyle), onPressed: () {});

  static ButtonStyle styleFrom({
    Color? primary,
    Color? onPrimary,
    Color? onSurface,
    Color? shadowColor,
    double? elevation,
    TextStyle? textStyle,
    EdgeInsetsGeometry? padding,
    Size? minimumSize,
    Size? fixedSize,
    BorderSide? side,
    OutlinedBorder? shape,
    MouseCursor? enabledMouseCursor,
    MouseCursor? disabledMouseCursor,
    VisualDensity? visualDensity,
    MaterialTapTargetSize? tapTargetSize,
    Duration? animationDuration,
    bool? enableFeedback,
    AlignmentGeometry? alignment,
    InteractiveInkFeatureFactory? splashFactory,
  }) {
    final MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? backgroundColor = (onSurface == null && primary == null)
        ? null
        : _ElevatedButtonDefaultBackground(primary, onSurface);
    final MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? foregroundColor = (onSurface == null && onPrimary == null)
        ? null
        : _ElevatedButtonDefaultForeground(onPrimary, onSurface);
    final MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? overlayColor = (onPrimary == null)
        ? null
        : _ElevatedButtonDefaultOverlay(onPrimary);
    final MaterialStateProperty<double>? elevationValue = (elevation == null)
        ? null
        : _ElevatedButtonDefaultElevation(elevation);
    final MaterialStateProperty<MouseCursor?>? mouseCursor = (enabledMouseCursor == null && disabledMouseCursor == null)
        ? null
        : _ElevatedButtonDefaultMouseCursor(enabledMouseCursor, disabledMouseCursor);

    return ButtonStyle(
      textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle?>(textStyle),
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      foregroundColor: foregroundColor,
      overlayColor: overlayColor,
      shadowColor: ButtonStyleButton.allOrNull<Color>(shadowColor),
      elevation: elevationValue,
      padding: ButtonStyleButton.allOrNull<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(padding),
      minimumSize: ButtonStyleButton.allOrNull<Size>(minimumSize),
      fixedSize: ButtonStyleButton.allOrNull<Size>(fixedSize),
      side: ButtonStyleButton.allOrNull<BorderSide>(side),
      shape: ButtonStyleButton.allOrNull<OutlinedBorder>(shape),
      mouseCursor: mouseCursor,
      visualDensity: visualDensity,
      tapTargetSize: tapTargetSize,
      animationDuration: animationDuration,
      enableFeedback: enableFeedback,
      alignment: alignment,
      splashFactory: splashFactory,
    );
  }

  @override
  ButtonStyle defaultStyleOf(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = theme.colorScheme;

    final EdgeInsetsGeometry scaledPadding = ButtonStyleButton.scaledPadding(
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
      MediaQuery.maybeOf(context)?.textScaleFactor ?? 1,
    );

    return styleFrom(
      primary: colorScheme.primary,
      onPrimary: null,//colorScheme.onPrimary,
      onSurface: colorScheme.onSurface,
      shadowColor: theme.shadowColor,
      elevation: 2,
      textStyle: theme.textTheme.button,
      padding: scaledPadding,
      minimumSize: const Size(64, 36),
      side: null,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))),
      enabledMouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
      disabledMouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.forbidden,
      visualDensity: theme.visualDensity,
      tapTargetSize: theme.materialTapTargetSize,
      animationDuration: kThemeChangeDuration,
      enableFeedback: true,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
    );
  }

}
```

and voilá! the color from TextStyle was used!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To change the textColor by setting the properties of elevated button you need to set onPrimary property as per docs the purpose of it is to style the text but the thing is the overlay onPrimary is used for purpose of giving effects or button feel which inturn affects on the color provided by text style:

> Specify a value for onPrimary to specify the color of the button's
> text and icons as well as the overlay colors used to indicate the
> hover, focus, and pressed states. Use primary for the button's
> background fill color and onSurface to specify the button's disabled
> text, icon, and fill color.
> [Follow here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/styleFrom.html)

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          onPrimary: Colors.black, //adding this would work
      ),
      child: Text('Hello'),
    )
```

Another way you can do is directly add the property to the text which is a workaround:

```
 ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          
      ),
      child:Text('Hello',style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Came to the same challenge as you have, using `Flutter 2.5.3.`.
I have used `foregroundColor` property for a button, instead of `textStyle` property.

The solution should be the following:

```
ElevatedButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.lightBlue), //optional
        ), //ButtonStyle
    child: Text("Hello"),
    onPressed: null) //ElevatedButton
```

[image: ElevatedButton foregroundColor property]

Answer (score 0):

It's used for decoration style. For example:

```
child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('Hello'),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        textStyle: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline, decorationColor: Colors.red, decorationThickness: 2)
    )
)
```

[image: elevated_button]

(red underline with thickness factor 2)